# Geometric Distribution problem

Tags: probability-distributions

Home work assignment i'm struggling with , i've been on this for an hour and  have nothing :

Let $X_1, \ldots X_n$ be a group of independent variables with geometric distribution: $X_i \sim \operatorname{Geom}(p_i)$. Let $Y = \min \{X_1 , \ldots , X_n\}$.

How is $Y$ distributed?

Comment: Can you handle from here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Related_distributions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

- A random variable $X$ is geometric with parameter $p$ if and only if $\mathbb P(X\geqslant k)=$$_______$ for every $k\geqslant0$.
- The random variable $Y=\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is such that $[Y\geqslant k]=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n[X_i\geqslant k]$ and the random variables $(X_i)_i$ are independent hence $\mathbb P(Y\geqslant k)=\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=1}^n$$______$ for every $n\geqslant0$.